# How would you go about fixing or improving the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class App extends React.Component {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: this.props.name || 'Anonymous'
    }
  }    
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Hello {this.state.name}</p>
    );  
  }
}
```

remove the state and use props by implementing below? if so how do you do it?

```
getDerivedStateFromProps
```

or (preferably) change to function components?

Looking forward to suggestions!

Comment: This depends on your case. The code you posted doesn't look like real app. It doesn't need props or a state at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go, a single line stateless component :

```
const App = ({ name }) => <p>Hello {name || 'Anonymous'}</p>
```

It has the exact same behavior as your class